# probability distribution and expected value.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, hypergeometric-function

A certain town performs a survey and discovers that 15% of their population have hazel-coloured eyes.

a.  If 5 people are randomly selected from the town, what is the probability that 2 of the people have hazel eyes?

b.  What is the expected number of people with hazel eyes in the group of 5 people?

c.  Create a probability histogram for the above situation for the outcomes from 0 to 5 people with hazel eyes.

Answer (score 1):

what's the population of the town?

a. use binomial distribution

b. find the probability that $k$ people have hazel eyes and hen solve $\sum_{k=0}^{5} k P(X=k)$

c. use you finding in b

Comment: how would i be able to use the binomial distribution, the percentage is not making sense to me.

Comment: have you worked with Binomial distribution before? Here $n=5, \ p_s = .15$

Comment: Is it like this, 
$0.15=(5C2)(0.15^2)(0.85^3)$

Comment: yes. where does $3.33$ come from?

Comment: the formula is $P(x)=(nCx)(p^x)(q^(n-x))$

Comment: sorry its 3 not 33.33 cause $n-x=5-2=3$

Comment: yes that's right